# I wrote a graphics program in c language. In this program I want to make a circle but after compiling I am not getting output

Tags: c, bgi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <graphics.h>

void main()
{
    int gd = 0, gm;
    clrscr();
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\TurboC++\Disk\TurboC3\BGI");
    circle(100, 80, 20);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

Comment: what BGI, OS, compiler&linker target you got ? original BGI is for 16bit MS-DOS code ... that will not work under windows/unix ... there are ports like WinBGI for windows however those are IIRC only 32bit so your compiler&linker target must be 32bit too if used... if you are under MS-DOS you need to set the compiler&linker for 16 bit code ... do not use `[graphics]` tag for `[BGI]` !!!

Comment: also you are calling clrsc before initgraph !!! and init graph using `C:\TurboC++\Disk\TurboC3\BGI` driver, are you sure it is present at that location?